# Accessing content of Balloon clicked in Google Earth plugin

Tags: c#-4.0, google-earth-plugin, winforms-interop

I have a Google earth plug-in and I have made various Placemarks and the balloon using the Winform library in c#. Now, i can see those Placemarks on the map and when i click the placemark, i can see the content i have parsed.

Now, my requirement is that when user clicks the balloon, i want to display the content of that balloon displayed in a text box outside the plug-in.

I am not finding any way where it can be recorded a which Placemark has been clicked and i can access the content of the balloon.

Can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find all the info you need here

https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/balloons

Edit:
I am not sure of your approach to show the text in your webpage, try something like this

```
      function addData(text) { 
           // var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("Mytextbox"); 
           // TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + text;
           document.getElementById('Mytextbox').innerHTML = '<p>' + text + '</p>';

           // if still having problems, try using an alert to see value of your 'text'
           alert(text);
      }
```

another idea - instead of listening for a balloonopening, listen for a click

```
      google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), 'click', placemarkClicked);


      function placemarkClicked(event) {
           var obj = event.getTarget();
           // determine if the user clicked on a Placemark
           if (obj.getType() == 'KmlPlacemark') {
               event.preventDefault();
               var placemark = obj;
               var placemark_name = placemark.getName();
               var placemark_desc_active = placemark.getBalloonHtmlUnsafe();

           // proceed to use the name and description as you like
```

Comment: Hi I have treid this documentaiton but nothing specific to my query is over there. I have used the follwing code to access the balloon clicked on the plugin.

    google.earth.addEventListener(feature, action,     events_.generic[hash], useCapture,initCB);
google.earth.addEventListener(ge, 'balloonopening', function(event) {event.preventDefault();var placemark = event.getBalloon().getFeature();var placemark_desc = placemark.getDescription();var placemark_name = placemark.getName();var placemark_desc_active = placemark.getBalloonHtmlUnsafe();addData(placemark_desc_active );});

Comment: Further in the function addData i have done the follwing to add this text to the textBox i have created:

function addData(text){
    var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("Mytextbox");
    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + text;
  }

But i dont see any text in the box when i click the balloon.